# Editext cursor blinking in two place after translation animation

Tags: android, animation, translation, android-relativelayout, android-animation

I have written code to translate the `Relativelayout` which contains three `edittext`.

when I tap on a particular edittext, Translation is working fine, but, the edittext cursor is blinking in both original position and translated position. I want to remove the original position's focus.

Here is my code,

```
 TranslateAnimation slide;

                 slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE, x1,Animation.ABSOLUTE, y1,Animation.ABSOLUTE,y1-i );



                getReLay(R.id.up_lay).invalidate();
                slide.setDuration(250);
                getReLay(R.id.up_lay).startAnimation(slide);
                slide.setFillAfter(true);
                fiftytemp=fifty+total;
                newTemp=i;
```

Note:
x1 is the left spacing ,y1 is the top spacing and i specifies the distance to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to request focus on the next edittext in code

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks, its a key hint